# start multiple processor threads on Spark worker within one core

Tags: multithreading, configuration, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

Our situation is: using Spark streaming with AWS Kinesis.

If specify the Spark master to be in memory as "**local[32]**", then Spark can consume data from Kinesis fairly quick.

But if we switch to a cluster with 1 master and 3 workers (on 4 separate machines), and set master to be "**spark://[IP]:[port]**", then the Spark cluster is consuming data at a very slow rate. This cluster has 3 worker machines, and each worker machine with 1 core.

I'm trying to speed up the consuming speed, so I add **more executors** on each worker machine, but it does not help much since each executor will need 1 core at least (and my worker machine has 1 core only). I also read adding more **Kinesis shard** number will help scale up, but I just want to maximize my read capacity.

Since the "in memory" mode is possible to consume fast enough, is it possible to also start multiple "Kinesis record processor thread" on each worker machine, shown in the **picture below**? Or start many threads to consume from Kinesis within 1 core?

Thank you very much.

picture below from https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-kinesis-integration.html

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be related to resources of the cluster.

For AWS Kinesis, one Kinesis stream requires one receiver from Spark cluster, and one receiver will acquire one core from Spark workers.

I increased the core of each worker to be 4 cores, and then executors have extra cores to run jobs.